# Unable to register WordPress blog account in MS Word 2010

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, wordpress

When I try to register for a blog account in MS Word 2010 I get the failure message pop up "Word cannot register your account. The provider where you are trying to publish is unavailable. Contact your provider for assistance." 

Here is the Microsoft article that guides how to use Word for blogging: 
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Help-with-blogging-in-Word-3ad4ad8d-06a3-441d-99cd-c65e13a3433d?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1

This is getting very frustrating because I can register using MS Word 2013 in another computer, and I have successfully published a post as well. At that point I'm on a conclusion that the remote posting of WordPress is enabled and working fine as usual.

I've tried tracing the responses using Fiddler and seems all are with the HTTP code 200 which means "OK".

Have anyone come across and resolved the same issue with Word 2010? I really need help.